# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable TreeNode object

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, queue, binary-tree

I am learning to use a deque to check if two binary trees are the same.  However, I can't figure out why n1 and n2 (as node1 and node2) can't be unpacked.  I tried to put them in a list and a tuple, unpacking, etc, but can't unpack successfully.  I'm thinking it's something else.  Could anyone help?  Here is the code:

```
    def iterative(self, p, q):
        q = deque( [p, q] )
        while len(q) > 0:
            n1, n2 = q.popleft()
            if not n1 and not n2:    pass
            elif not n1  or not n2:  return False
            else:
                if n1.val != n2.val: return False
                q.append( [n1.left, n2.left] )
                q.append( [n1.right, n2.right] )
        return True
```

Comment: The error indicates that the deque elements are `TreeNode` instances, not tuples.

Comment: Are you expecting `deque( [p, q] )` to append the list `[p, q]` to the deque? When you create a deque, each element of that list is a separate element in the deque. Use `deque([[p, q]])` to make the list the initial element of the deque.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in how you initialise the deque. The constructor expects an iterable of entries, and as you intend an entry to be a pair, you need to provide an *iterable* of pairs. But instead you provided just a pair, which it is interpreted as a sequence of *two* entries, each being a singe node and not a pair. This means your deque starts out with two entries instead of one, and each entry is a node, not a pair of nodes.

Change this:

```
q = deque( [p, q] )
```

to this:

```
q = deque( [[p, q]] )
```